# Executing child process in a seperate thread -- Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, threadpool

I need to execute some jobs based on the number of available threads in the thread pool. Each job is a child process being spawned on a separate thread. Once the child process finishes, it should update the pool size. If the pool size is 0,new jobs should wait till at least one of the child process terminates and the thread is ready to take up the next job.

How to proceed with this?

Comment: A good start would be to write some code that we can debug - it doesn't have to work, but you should try and solve your own problem first. The `threading` library will report the number of active threads

Comment: If you're spawning child *processes* then you shouldn't need to do so from separate threads. Each process executes within its own context, which includes its own threads. You should take a look at the `multiprocessing` module if you need to do concurrent programming.